# FutureBuilder and async function in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with FutureBuilder, it refresh and execute code again when there is a change like when i change value of radio button, i click on radio and it reloads all futurebuilder it seems. 
EDIT : i have corrected the problem and here is my solution, i am not sure it works all time

My full code is :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

// Create a Form widget.
class Affiche_grille extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Affiche_grille_State createState() {
    return _Affiche_grille_State();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.

class _Affiche_grille_State extends State<Affiche_grille> {
  @override
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> radioValues = [];
  Future<List<Match>> grid;

  Future <List<Match>> Grille_display() async {
    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'http://www.axis-medias.fr/game_app/display_grid.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_grille': 1};

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));

    // Getting Server response into variable.

    var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Match> Matchs = [];

    for (var u in jsondata) {
      Match match = Match(u["equipe1"],u["equipe2"],u["type_prono"]);
      Matchs.add(match);
      radioValues.add("N");
    }
    return Matchs;
  }

  void initState() {
    grid = Grille_display();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final appTitle = 'MONEYFREE';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child:
            FutureBuilder(
              future: grid,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Container (
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Chargement en cours...")
                    )
                  );
                }
                else {
                List<Match> values = snapshot.data;
                return Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          DataTable(
                            columnSpacing: 20,
                            columns: [
                              DataColumn(
                                label: Text("Libelle Match"),
                                numeric: false,
                                tooltip: "",
                              ),
                              DataColumn(
                                label: Text("1"),
                                numeric: false,
                                tooltip: "",
                              ),
                              DataColumn(
                                label: Text("N"),
                                numeric: false,
                                tooltip: "",
                              ),
                              DataColumn(
                                label: Text("2"),
                                numeric: false,
                                tooltip: "",
                              ),
                            ],
                            rows:
                            List.generate(values.length, (index) {
                              return DataRow(
                                  cells: [
                                    DataCell(
                                      Text(values[index].equipe1.toString() + " - " + values[index].equipe2.toString()),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Radio(
                                        value: "1",
                                        groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                        onChanged: (val) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            radioValues[index] = val;
                                            print('Change 1');
                                            print(radioValues);
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Radio(
                                        value: "N",
                                        groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                        onChanged: (val) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            radioValues[index] = val;
                                            print('Change N');
                                            print(radioValues);
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Radio(
                                        value: "2",
                                        groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                        onChanged: (val) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            radioValues[index] = val;
                                            print('Change 2');
                                            print(radioValues);
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                              child: Text('VALIDER VOTRE GRILLE'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Valide_grille();
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                  );
                };
                },
            ),
        ),
      ),
      );
  }

  Future Valide_grille() async{
    // For CircularProgressIndicator.
    bool visible = false ;
    // Showing CircularProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      visible = true ;
    });

    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'http://www.axis-medias.fr/game_app/valide_grid.php';

    var concatenate='';

    radioValues.forEach((item){
      concatenate=concatenate+item;
    });

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_membre':1, 'id_grille':1,'result':concatenate};

    print (data);

    var grille_encode=jsonEncode(data);

    print(grille_encode);

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: grille_encode);

    print(response.body);

    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var message = json.decode(response.body);

    // If the Response Message is Matched.
    if(message == 'OK')
    {
      print('VALIDATION DE LA GRILLE OK');
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

    }else{

      // If Email or Password did not Matched.
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

      // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
  }

class Match {

  final String equipe1;
  final String equipe2;
  final String typeprono;

  const Match(this.equipe1, this.equipe2, this.typeprono);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below

**Reason**

`didUpdateWidget` of the `FutureBuilder` state is being called every time a rebuild is issued. This function checks if the old future object is different from the new one, and if so, refires the `FutureBuilder`.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11426#issuecomment-414047398

**Solution**

```
Future _future;

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _future = Grille_display();
  }
 ... 
 child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

// Create a Form widget.
class Affiche_grille extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Affiche_grille_State createState() {
    return _Affiche_grille_State();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.

class _Affiche_grille_State extends State<Affiche_grille> {
  @override
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> radioValues = [];

  Future<List<Match>> Grille_display() async {
    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'http://www.axis-medias.fr/game_app/display_grid.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_grille': 1};

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));

    // Getting Server response into variable.

    var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Match> Matchs = [];

    for (var u in jsondata) {
      Match match = Match(u["equipe1"], u["equipe2"], u["type_prono"]);
      Matchs.add(match);
    }
    return Matchs;
  }

  Future _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _future = Grille_display();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'MONEYFREE';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Container(
                    child: Center(child: Text("Chargement en cours...")));
              } else {
                List<Match> values = snapshot.data;
                values.forEach((m) {
                  radioValues.add("N");
                  //like N or something
                });
                print('valeur radio après initialisation');
                print(radioValues);
                return Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        DataTable(
                          columnSpacing: 20,
                          columns: [
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text("Libelle Match"),
                              numeric: false,
                              tooltip: "",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text("1"),
                              numeric: false,
                              tooltip: "",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text("N"),
                              numeric: false,
                              tooltip: "",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text("2"),
                              numeric: false,
                              tooltip: "",
                            ),
                          ],
                          rows: List.generate(values.length, (index) {
                            return DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(
                                Text(values[index].equipe1.toString() +
                                    " - " +
                                    values[index].equipe2.toString()),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Radio(
                                  value: "1",
                                  groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      radioValues[index] = val;
                                      print('Change 1');
                                      print(radioValues);
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Radio(
                                  value: "N",
                                  groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      radioValues[index] = val;
                                      print(radioValues);
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              DataCell(
                                Radio(
                                  value: "2",
                                  groupValue: radioValues[index],
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      radioValues[index] = val;
                                      print(radioValues);
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]);
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                            child: Text('VALIDER VOTRE GRILLE'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Valide_grille();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ));
              }
              ;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future Valide_grille() async {
    // For CircularProgressIndicator.
    bool visible = false;
    // Showing CircularProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      visible = true;
    });

    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'http://www.axis-medias.fr/game_app/valide_grid.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = jsonEncode(radioValues);

    print(radioValues);
    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));

    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var message = json.decode(response.body);

    // If the Response Message is Matched.
    if (message == 'OK') {
      print('VALIDATION DE LA GRILLE OK');
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });
    } else {
      // If Email or Password did not Matched.
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

      // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}

class Match {
  final String equipe1;
  final String equipe2;
  final String typeprono;

  const Match(this.equipe1, this.equipe2, this.typeprono);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Affiche_grille(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i have found the solution, it seems little different of your, i am going to modify my first post for show you what i have done. It seems it works. Since i have done the validation action for send result of the radio buttons to an api. Now i need help for another small problem. I create a game application, the user need to create an account but after i need your experience, how works this kind of application normally, you create an account you log in and how you do on the member page for know it is this member who is connected (username, password),in php it is session but with flutter ?